# Prevent SQL Server reports caught errors to Java (Hibernate), JDBC driver

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, stored-procedures, jdbc, try-catch

A Java Hibernate application call my stored procedure in SQL Server 2019, through JDBC

The stored procedure has a begin/catch block

Despite I catch the error, the error is reported back to Java as an Exception
and then the application finishes with an error

From the database (and business) point of view, the error was caught, and everything is fine

I need Java application to not trigger an exception, since the error was correctly treated by the stored procedure

Is there any configuration or something (in the SP) I can add?

NOTE: I'm on the DB side, the Java code is not in my scope, it can't be modified

### ADDED

I mean, whatever kind of error, for example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_TEST
AS
BEGIN TRY
    SELECT 1/0 as x
    PRINT 'no problem'
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT 1 as x
    PRINT 'don´t pay attention'
END CATCH
PRINT 'good bye'

return 0 -- always 0 = OK
```

Despite the error was managed by the Stored Procedure
in some way the client application receives it

I really don't know if it is normal to the driver or the Engine

Comment: Add sample code for the stored procedure and error you'd like to suppress.

Comment: Are you using a T-SQL `CATCH` block? A JdbcException should not be raised on the client unless the error was re-thrown in the catch block.

Comment: Dan, next week I will able to post details about the client application, that is, the piece of Java code that catches the exception, and maybe some comments of the Java developer

Comment: What's the specific kind of exception reported in your Java application? Based on your posted code example I expect that it's an application-generated exception, not an SQL exception, because the `select 1/0` will still return a result set to the application - it will just have 1 unnamed column and 0 rows.

Comment: [duplicate on MS Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/651201/sql-server-how-does-engine-manage-errors-behind-th.html)

Comment: You are right, a mistake in the example. However, the actual SP doesn't return anything. (I can't post the actual SP). I'm seeing now, that the actual SP, in some place calls a second SP, that has a "RETURN -3000" at the end of CATCH block. Maybe this "bad status" ( <>0 ) is what the application/driver/client sees and then triggers an exception. That is, despite the error have been caught in the second SP, and the main SP is prepared to manage the bad status to finish ok. I think this is a good point. I'll be testing it